# What does a hash after a variable name do as an operator in bash?

Tags: bash

I found this code:

```
EXTENSION="${i#*=}"
```

What it does is to take the variable `$i`, which is an argument for the script and copies everything after the character `=`. So if I do something like `myscript.sh -e=wow`, it copies `wow` to `$EXTENSION`. But I want to know what the symbols `#*=` mean in this order? It seems like `#*` is together the copy all after and `=` is the character after which it copies, or is it more complex?

Answer (score 15):

That is an example of *prefix removal*.  The general form is:

```
 ${variable#pattern}
```

which removes the shortest match to the glob `pattern` from the beginning of `variable`.  In your case, `pattern` consists of (a) `*` which matches zero or more of any character, and (b) `=` which matches just `=`.

See `man bash` for more info.

#### Example

```
$ i='ab=cd'
$ echo "${i#a}" 
b=cd
$ echo "${i#*=}" 
cd
```

Answer (score 6):

> ### [Bash Reference Manual](//www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html)
>
> #### [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](//www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)
>
> […]
>
> ```
> ${parameter#word}
> ```
>
> The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion (see [Filename Expansion](//www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion)). If the pattern matches the
>   beginning of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the
>   expansion is the expanded value of parameter with the shortest
>   matching pattern […] deleted.

#### Example

```sh
$ i='ab=cd'
$ echo "${i#a}" 
b=cd
$ echo "${i#*=}" 
cd
```

<sup>Shamelessly stolen from [John's answer](/a/706437/175814)</sup>